# Time in hour:Minute:second format in j2me

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I trying to make a method that return a String that expresses of current time in j2me or lwuit framework at hour:Minute:Second  Format.

If I use the following code the output will be:

`Wed Mar 06 13:55:45 GMT+03:00 2013` (only I need `13:55:45`)

```
public String   Refresh() {
    java.util.Date t = new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis() );
    String tt = t.toString();
    return tt;
}
```

And if I use the following code   Refresh method  always returns  `3:0:0` !!!

```
java.util.Calendar calendar;
public String   Refresh() {
     calendar = calendar.getInstance();
     StringBuffer time = new StringBuffer();
     time.append(calendar.get(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)).append(':');
     time.append(calendar.get(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE)).append(':');
     time.append(calendar.get(java.util.Calendar.SECOND));
     String tt = time.toString();
     return tt;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's going to work, but what about using: `calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());` after `getInstance`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Date myDate = new Date(); // May be your date too.
calendar.setTime(myDate);
```

I think this will work.

Answer (score 0):

**R.j**    thankfully has solved my problem.

So the complete code will be

```
public String   Refresh()
    {

    calendar = calendar.getInstance();
    Date myDate = new Date();  
calendar.setTime(myDate);
     StringBuffer time = new StringBuffer();
     time.append(calendar.get(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)).append(':');
     time.append(calendar.get(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE)).append(':');
     time.append(calendar.get(java.util.Calendar.SECOND));
     String tt = time.toString();
     return tt;


}
```